# ¿Cómo pasarle parámetros al método initModule?

Tags: extjs, constructor

Estoy creando una pantalla de mi aplicación a la que necesitaría pasarle una serie de parámetros, de los cuales depende el tipo y contenido de ventana que se creará. He probado varias maneras pero no me ha funcionado ninguna.

A modo de ejemplo me bastaría con saber como pasarle 2 parámetros al método `initModule` en una llamada de este tipo:

```
this.app.initModule('App.view.NuevoMotivo', {
        modulo: this,
        newMotivo: true,
        numTotal: this.total
        //otro params, etc...
});
```

La idea es que el mismo módulo `NuevoMotivo` me sirva tanto para crear/editar motivos pasándole una simple variable booleana. Así sería el código de la función llamada al tratarse de un **nuevo**:

```
, nuevoMotivo: function () {
    this.app.initModule('App.view.NuevoMotivo', {
        modulo: this,
        newMotivo: true
    });
}
```

Y así al tratarse de la **edición** de un Motivo ya existente:

```
, editarMotivo: function (view, record) {
    this.app.initModule('App.view.NuevoMotivo', {
        modulo: this,
        newMotivo: false  // booleano => modo edición
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, finalmente lo solucioné. Se trataba de que el mismo método `initModule` necesitaba más parámetros de entrada con llamadas de este tipo:

```
this.app.initModule('isf.rcl.mdlNuevoMotivoClasificado', null, {
        record: record,
        modulo: this,
        newMotivo: false    //booleano => modo edición
    });
```